# how to make a multi line plot by ID and overlay with event

Tags: r, ggplot2, overlay

I have a data set that looks like this:
[image]

The sample data can be build by the codes:

```
ID<-c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3","4","4","4","4")
Days<-c("-5","1","18","30","1","8","16","1","8","6","-6","1","7","15")
Event<-c("","","P","","","","N","","","C","","","P","N")
Test_1<-c("82","95","67","99","58","57","68","25","87","68","77","87","98","55")
Test_2<-c("66","85","96","35","27","69","55","27","39","24","55","99","89","58")

Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Days, Event, Test_1, Test_2)
```

I would like to make a plot that look like this but have no clue how to make it. It is too complex for me to even make a sample plot in excel. so I hand draw one to show what I want to achieve. Sorry for the ugly graph. Anyone can help and guide me on this? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a good point to start. Please next time do not include all values in variables between quotes. Only characters must be quoted in `R`. I inspected your data and found a way to obtain a similar curves to what you want. I do not understand the variable `Event` as this has empty values. But using a long format data you can be able to create a similar plot using score values in test variables. Here the code using functions from `tidyverse` packages `ggplot2`, `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
ID<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
Days<-c(-5,1,18,30,1,8,16,1,8,6,-6,1,7,15)
Test_1<-c(82,95,67,99,58,57,68,25,87,68,77,87,98,55)
Test_2<-c(66,85,96,35,27,69,55,27,39,24,55,99,89,58)
Event<-c("","","P","","","","N","","","C","","","P","N")
#Dataframe
Sample.data <- data.frame(ID, Days, Event, Test_1, Test_2,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Reshape
Sample.data %>% pivot_longer(-c(1:3)) %>%
  mutate(Event=ifelse(Event=="",NA,Event)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Days,y=value,group=name,color=name,label=Event))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(0.9),show.legend = F)+
  facet_wrap(.~ID)+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Wow. You are fast. Event is the specail event that might happen during the timeline. I want to mark it on the time point. how to I mark it on the line, add a line or add a letter? Also, if I have lot of ID(45), how should i produce a group of plots(6 pages in pdf?) which has 9 IDs in each graph?

Comment: @Stataq I have added an update, I hope that can be useful. In the case of what you want try playing with `nrow()` and `ncol()` options in `facet_wrap()` you can tune so that you can have different matrix of plots and isolate each plot in a new object in order to use `pdf()` to export :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried `facet_wrap(.~ID,  nrow =3, ncol = 3)` and get 
Error: The given dimensions cannot hold all panels. Please increase `ncol` or `nrow`. What should I do? This is for 54 IDs

Comment: @Stataq Be careful with that because if you have 45 possible plots, 3x3 will try to include only the first nine ids. You can play around that :)

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. If I put 54 in a page, it is too small. is it possible to separate them into 9 at a time? If not, Can i make plot one at a time?

Comment: @Stataq Yes you can, you could isolate the data with filters and then plot. If you want more clear explanation you can invite me to chat. It is a pleasure help anyone else!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221587/discussion-between-stataq-and-duck).